# Bootstrap 5 carousel not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to embed this carousel in my Bootstrap 5 page. It comes from Codepen - https://codepen.io/sahil-verma/pen/wxXryx

So far, I've copied the code in my webpage, and embedded the corresponding CSS in style tags something like this

```
<div class="container">
      <style media="screen">
      #quote-carousel {
  padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-control {
  background: none;
  color: #CACACA;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  text-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators {
  position: relative;
  right: 50%;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: -19px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .4s ease-in;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.item blockquote {
  border-left: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.item blockquote p:before {
  content: "\f10d";
  font-family: 'Fontawesome';
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
      </style>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
                    <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
                        <!-- Quote 1 -->
                        <div class="item active">
                            <blockquote>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. !</p>
                                        <small>Someone famous</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Quote 2 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <blockquote>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
                                        <small>Someone famous</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Quote 3 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <blockquote>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. .</p>
                                        <small>Someone famous</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img class="img-responsive " src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/mantia/128.jpg" alt="">
                        </li>
                        <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg" alt="">
                        </li>
                        <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brad_frost/128.jpg" alt="">
                        </li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
                    <a data-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <a data-slide="next" href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://thecodeblock.com/create-a-quote-testimonial-slider-using-bootstrap-carousel"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back to Article</a>
    </div>
```

What I'm getting is this
[image]

I can't figure out for the love of God what is going wrong here. The carousel just won't work. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here. There's another carousel on the page which works just fine. I've also tried this same code in a Bootstrap 4 setting with no carousels but I get the same result.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser's developer console? any 404 or something like that?

Comment: I do see a 403 Forbidden on line 543, 545 and 547. Those are all lines at the end of the carousel's code

Comment: Could you provide your full code for us to try it?

Comment: @pazitos10 I see a couple of 403 errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Are those 403 the same as in the codepen you provided? If so, those rounded images are not being loaded properly but it is not related to your problem. The problem here seems to be related to styles not being properly defined. If you look closely to the css configuration in the codepen link you provided, the example uses bootstrap 3 (look at the cdn URLs).

Comment: You probably will need to adapt your styles and update your html classes to match how bootstrap 5 carousels are meant to be used in the current version.

Comment: As far as I know, the carousel should work just fine regardless of the bootstrap version but there's definitely something missing so lemme see what changes I need to make and get back to you.

Comment: I swapped the cdn URLs and apparently works just fine as you said before, my bad. I think, the other possible explanation could be how your css rules are being defined. Unfortunately I don't know if you have more rules that could be breaking the ones used by the carousel components.

Comment: its `.carousel-item` not `.item`

Comment: @pazitos10 I haven't got any other CSS rules interfering with this so I really don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using the wrong `.item` class. This should be like below:

```html
<div class="carousel-item">
  <blockquote>
    ...
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

That will fix the display.

Next, you have missed the data attribute prefix in several places (used in BS5) go through your code and add `bs-` where needed (`data-bs-ride`, `data-bs-target`, `data-bs-slide`, etc.) and the carousel will work as expected.
See my working snipet:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <style media="screen">
      #quote-carousel {
        padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
        margin-top: 60px;
      }
      
      #quote-carousel .carousel-control {
        background: none;
        color: #CACACA;
        font-size: 2.3em;
        text-shadow: none;
        margin-top: 30px;
      }
      
      #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators {
        position: relative;
        right: 50%;
        top: auto;
        bottom: 0px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: -19px;
      }
      
      #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-radius: 50%;
        opacity: 0.4;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all .4s ease-in;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      
      #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active {
        width: 128px;
        height: 128px;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all .2s;
      }
      
      .item blockquote {
        border-left: none;
        margin: 0;
      }
      
      .item blockquote p:before {
        content: "\f10d";
        font-family: 'Fontawesome';
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
          <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
          <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
            <!-- Quote 1 -->
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <blockquote>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <p>ONE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. !</p>
                    <small>Someone famous</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
            <!-- Quote 2 -->
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <blockquote>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <p>TWO Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
                    <small>Someone famous</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
            <!-- Quote 3 -->
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <blockquote>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <p>THREE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. .</p>
                    <small>Someone famous</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-bs-target="#quote-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"><img class="img-responsive " src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/mantia/128.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li data-bs-target="#quote-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li data-bs-target="#quote-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brad_frost/128.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
          <a data-bs-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a data-bs-slide="next" href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://thecodeblock.com/create-a-quote-testimonial-slider-using-bootstrap-carousel"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back to Article</a>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/

Comment: This works but there are still issues with the styling. The text blocks appear on the far left, image circles on the far right and the carousel control buttons at the bottom.

Comment: There's also an issue with the carousel images. No matter what I put int the `src` the images won't apply.

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it solves the initial problem of the carousel. The rest is CSS being broken.